# Can't seem to add a line feed to the end of HTMLBody (<br /> tag getting trimmed)

Tags: html, .net, mailitem

We're creating an Outlook mailitem and setting up a part of the message body. However the client wants the message body to end with a clean fresh line so he can add further text.

It's a trivial request but ...

It seems adding anything which isn't a character or else `&nbsp;` to the end of `.HTMLBody` is ignored/trimmed off.

We want our mail message to end with a new line but we're finding:

---

### tried 1

```
x.HTMLBody = CustomerName & "," & "<p>"
```

and

```
x.HTMLBody = CustomerName & "," & "<br>"
```

and

```
x.HTMLBody = CustomerName & "," & "<br><br>"
```

all result in:

```
Mr MAWHOOD,
           ^ = cursor positioned here
```

this isn't what the client wants ... he wants the cursor to start on a fresh line

---

### tried 2

```
x.HTMLBody = CustomerName & "," & "<br>&nbsp;"
```

results in:

```
Mr MAWHOOD,

 ^ = cursor positioned here (one space in)
```

this is slightly better ... but still client wants to know why we have this "hacky" space on our new line

---

### tried 3

```
x.HTMLBody = CustomerName & "," & "<p>&nbsp;</p><br />"
```

results in:

```
Mr MAWHOOD,



^ = cursor positioned here (correct, but now two lines down)
```

strange that the only way to get a new trimmed line is we accept we have to have two of them?

---

Comment: Have you tried to end with 2 <br /> tags?

Comment: Have you checked this in any other email client apart from Outlook? Even web-based ones.

Comment: I've looked further at it and it seems that removing trailing <br /> tags is normal behaviour for a html page, what the mail body will be.

I've created a simple html page in notepad, and the trailing breaks are also removed there.

The code in your "tried 3" section gave me the same result there with or without the <br/>, it still gets trimmed there. That one also gives me a space at the end.

Comment: @abhitalks it's an in-house system and Outlook is what they have in-house

Comment: @hawbsl: does this work? `x.HTMLBody = "<p style='margin-bottom: 32px;'>" & CustomerName & "</p>" & "<br />"`

Answer (score 0):

You should try your second approach, but add the

```
&#08;
```

HTML character at the end. This is the backspace character, and may take off that "hacky" space after the line break. So

```
x.HTMLBody = CustomerName & "," & "<br />&nbsp;&#08;"
```

I found it here: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_ascii.asp
However I can't be certain it will work, and it probably won't....

Comment: thanks for the tip ... but you're right. i've tried it and for me (at least) it doesn't work